# Code fails to give expected result, stacking loops

Tags: c

I'm a student and I'm currently learning C without much experience on programming, I've been trying to create a program that receives a "password" from the user and then proceeds to check if the password has at least one letter,number and special character. I wrote some code but it doesn't give the expected results while I struggle to find what's wrong with it.

If I input a "just numbers" password or "just special characters" it does fine by returning "You missed a letter"

If I input a "just characters" password it doesn't return anything, same for a normal password that contains all 3

That's the code:

```
int main()
{
   char a[20];
   int b = 0 ,c = 0,d=0;
   printf("Please type your password and make sure it contains a letter a number and a special character:");
   scanf("%s",a);
   while(b<=20){                                                    
        if(isalpha(a[b])){
            break;
            while(c<=20){                                              
                if(isdigit(a[c])){
                    break;
                    while(d<=20){                                  
                        if(isalpha(a[d]) || isdigit(a[d])){
                           d++; continue;                         
                        }else{
                            printf("Congratulations your Password has been saved\n");
                            }
                        } printf("You missed a special character\n");
                }else{c++; continue;}                               
            }
            printf("You missed a number\n");
        }else{b++; continue;}                                      
}
(b>20) ? printf("You missed a letter\n") : printf("");
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You should only have one loop, looping over the characters of the string. Furthermore, the checks are independent, so they should be one after the other (not nested).

Comment: What is the reason for all of the nested loops?

Comment: loop through the password once. Is the current char a letter? a number? a special char? Save the answer to each of those questions, and at the end of the loop, check them and print out any appropriate error messages.

Comment: The ternary statement at the end is the reason that some programming style guides forbid the use of the ternary operator. The ternary operator is useful in some situations. This is not one of them.

Comment: The code does not check for a "special" character with `if(isalpha(a[d]) || isdigit(a[d]))` which should be `if(!isalpha(a[d]) && !isdigit(a[d]))`, but as suggested above, it is better to use `if(isalpha(a[d]))` ... `else if(isdigit(a[d]))` ... `else /* special */`.

Comment: Rewrite it. When you 'break' you get out of loop. If you want to go back to the start of loop use 'continue'. Pass it a small string and test by getting number of letters and number of digits. If you want to use b as your counter I would use a for( b=0 ; a[b] ; b++)